# Separating a first order linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a first order linear differential equation (a variation on a draining mixing tank problem) with many constants, and want to separate variables to solve it.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = k_1 + k_2 \frac{y}{k_3 + k_4t}$$

$y$ is the amount of mass in the tank at time $t$, and for simplicity, I've reduced various terms to constants, $k_1$ through $k_4$.

Separation of variables is made difficult by $k_1$, and I've considered an integrating factor, but think I might be missing something simple.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to approach this is use an integrating factor.

First, recognize the problem as a first order linear differential equation of the form:

\begin{equation*}
    y^{\prime}(t) + p(t) y = q(t)
\end{equation*}

Which has a solution:

\begin{equation}
    (u(t) \cdot y)' = u(t) \cdot q(t)
\label{if}
\end{equation}

Next, find the integration factor $u(t)$:

\begin{equation*}
    u = e ^{\int p(t) dt} 
\end{equation*}

And substitute back into the second equation to solve.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = k_1 + k_2 \frac{y}{k_3 + k_4t}$$
For simplicity substitute $u=k_3 + k_4t$:
$$k_4\frac{dy}{du} = k_1 + k_2 \frac{y}{u}$$
$$  y'-\dfrac {k_2}{k_4u}y=\dfrac {k_1}{k_4}$$
Solve the homogeneous DE and use variation of parameter method for the inhomogeneous DE:
$$y'-\dfrac {k_2}{k_4u}y=0$$